# Rotman's exercise 2.8 "$S_n$ cannot be imbedded in $A_{n+1}$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

This question is about the (in)famous Rotman's exercise 2.8 in "*An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*."
I've searched and found similar questions here and in MO, ***but*** none of them contains a valid proof. ([Does $S_n$ belong as a subgroup to $A_{n+1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83160/does-s-n-belong-as-a-subgroup-to-a-2n1))

According to Rotman, a valid proof can only use the concepts introduced up to this exercise: cycle permutations, factorization of permutations, odd and even permutations, semigroups, groups, homomorphism and subgroups. Cosets, Lagrange's theorem, normal subgroups, and so on are **not** yet introduced. I stress this point because all of the proofs I've seen use Lagrange or actions, on cosets.

Now my attempt is to use exercise 2.7 (solved) which is about a proof that $A_n$ ($n>2$) is generated by all the $3$-cycles and exercise 2.4 (solved) " if $S$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ then $\langle G \setminus S\rangle=G$ " in this way:

Suppose that for every $\phi  : S_n \to A_{n+1}$ imbeddings, all the $ 3$-cycles are contained in $\operatorname{Im}\phi $, then the assertion is proved by absurd. But I can't find a way to prove if it is possible or either find a counterexample to this kind of approach.

If someone has another proof which use only basics concepts is well accepted of course, but I mainly need  some hints about correctness or not of my reasoning and how to proceed if it is correct. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not very sure about the way i am following as you said i can not use more group theory but, Suppose $S_n$ is in $A_{n+1}$, what is the order of $S_n$ and what is the order of $A_{n+1}$... does $n!$ divides $\frac{(n+1)!}{2}$ in general....

Comment: @Praphulla yeah yeah but you are using Lagrange in this way, and in this way you only eliminate half of the cases,thanks anyway

Comment: ok, after getting used to lagrange theorem, it would be difficult to check from basics ;).. any ways, I am helpless.. All the Best :)

Comment: Have you tried counting the number of elements of order $2$ in both $S_n$ and $A_{n+1}$? The computations are rather cumbersome, but it requires no knowledge of group theory.

Comment: Not tried yet, I'll try this approach

Comment: The answer you are looking for can be found [here][1].


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83160/does-s-n-belong-as-a-subgroup-to-a-2n1?rq=1

Comment: The only answer I see there use the concepts of Index, simple group or normal subgroups. I can't use these concepts. And yeah I've read that question dozen of time but I don't think it is an exhaustive answer (again, there are "too advanced" concepts involved ) thanks anyway

Comment: @user84559: I thought counting elements of order 2 might work too, but it doesn't. To save doing the combinatorics here, http://oeis.org/A000085 and http://oeis.org/A000704 give the relevant counts and the only case where $S_n$ has more elements of order 2 than $A_{n+1}$ is when $n = 2$.

Comment: Isn't there a result that the largest subgroup of $A_{n+1}$ is $A_n$? I may be mistaken.

Comment: Here is a link to an answer at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65083/an-easy-proof-that-sn-does-not-embed-into-an1

Comment: see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h333049

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth it uses that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$. Far from the what Rotman covered up to that chapter. Cosets are NOT covered either.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what exactly I'm allowed to use or what Rotman had in mind, but I think this approach uses no more group theory than the (unique) factorization of permutations and the basic idea of what a homomorphism is.

If $n$ is odd there exists a subset $S\subset S_n$ of pairwise commuting elements of order $2$ with $|S|=\tfrac{n-1}{2}$. For example
$$\{(1\ 2),(3\ 4),\ldots,(n-2\ n-1)\}.$$
An element $\sigma\in A_{n+1}$ of order $2$ is necessarily a product of an even number of disjoint $2$-cycles. Therefore a subset $A\subset A_{n+1}$ of pairwise commuting elements of order $2$ cannot contain more than $\tfrac{n+1}{4}$ elements. Hence for an embedding $S_n\ \hookrightarrow\ A_{n+1}$ to exist we must have
$$\frac{n-1}{2}\leq\frac{n+1}{4},$$
or equivalently $n\leq3$. At this point it should not be hard to verify that $S_3$ does not embed into $A_4$, and of course that $S_1$ *does* embed into $A_2$.

A similar argument can be made when $n$ is even, to find that for an embedding $S_n\ \hookrightarrow\ A_{n+1}$ to exist we must have
$$\frac{n}{2}<\frac{n+1}{4},$$
or equivalently $n<1$, immediately yielding a contradiction.

Comment: Woow, I need to sit down and check it, anyway, thanks for this answer, seems to be plausible, but again, I've yet to read it carefully! :)

Comment: Though it seemed like a good idea at 03:00 AM last night, I see now that my proof doesn't work. But perhaps it can be saved. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: From your comment I conclude that you realized in meanwhile that $A_4$ has an elementary abelian subgroup of order $4$, i.e., two commuting elements of order $2$.