# A group with order 12 with three elements of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Show that $A_4$ (which has order $12$) has exactly three elements of order $2$.

Additional information: $A_4$ denotes the set of even permutations in $S_4$. $S_4$ is defined as all of the permutations of size 4. $|S_n| = n!$ and an earlier exercise in the book I'm using (Hungerford, Abstract Algebra) shows that $|A_n| = n!/2$. There's no hint in the book and the exercise comes from Chapter 8.1 Exercise 44.

**Edit:**
I've recently begun to learn about finding isomorphisms to a certain group using multiplication tables along with the knowledge of cosets (right-cosets specifically) and Lagrange's Theorem.

I think that the way to solve this problem might be to consider the elements of $A_4$ with orders 2,3 or 6. In general I'm feeling a bit lost in this field so I would really appreciate if someone had a good explanation.

Comment: What definition of $A_4$ are you working with?  Do you have a set of generators and relations?

Comment: To get worthwhile help, you should say what you already know, and what you’ve tried. Many of us can hand you the answer on a plate, but that will not be any help to you.

Comment: Here's a link so that you can see the Cayley table: it shows you flat out which have order 2:  http://acunix.wheatonma.edu/jsklensk/Abstract_Fall08/classwork/november/nov3-inclass.pdf

Answer (score 3):

clearly the $2-$cycle doesn't lie in $A_4$ (for some basic reference see [the Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) about this fact). So what are the elements of order 2 in here?

**A few facts:** --try to prove or recall--

1)the order of the product of two disjoint cycles is the lcm of their orders.

2) two - cycles have order 2, **but they don't lie in A_4**. But you have **4 different element to permute**, so using the rule of signs for permutations you can conclude

3) there are nice books which treat these properties and basics fact very well (**and it is important to understand them very well**), for an introductory level you can start reading "Humpreys - A course in Group Theory", and when you feel more confident you can start trying to solve the exercise in "Rotman - An Introduction to the Theory of Groups". Maybe you can find an answer to my old question [$S_n$ cannot be imbedded in $A_{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470469/rotmans-exercise-2-8-s-n-cannot-be-imbedded-in-a-n1) for every $n$, answer I'm very interested to see :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've realized, just as you point out, that the 2-cycles are their own permutations but since they are odd they do not belong in A_4. Do you have a good method on listing the elements of A_4? If I understand your answer correctly, you're suggesting that I should find 4 elements and use the rule of signs. How should I find these elements and what's the rule of signs?

Comment: First of all, in this case I spoken about elements referring to the elements of the set,(an element of $A_4$ is a permutation over such set). It is irrelevant what this set is, it has four element. **the rule of signs** is basically the fact you have a group morphism "sign" from $S_n$ to $C_2$ (the cyclic group with two elements), so $sign(ab)=sign(a)sign(b)$. $A_n$ is the kernel of such morphism (and so it's a normal subgroup of $S_n$)

Comment: (Calling the element of $C_2$ $1,a$ with $a^2=1$ -obviously it is the only way to make a set with two element a group) So if you have two odd permutations $\varphi$ and $\pi$, then $sign(\varphi)=a$ , $sign(\pi)=a$ and by the fact **that $sign$ is a morphism** $sign(\varphi \pi) =sign(\varphi)sign(\pi)=a^2=1$ so the product is a element of the kernel of $sign$ and so it belongs to $A_n$.

Comment: @Ludwwwig and lastly, you need an even permutation of order two. You have the two-cycles whose order is $2$, but **if you could multiplying** them by **another odd disjoint permutation of order two**, you would have an even permutation of order the lcm of $2$ and $2$, so $2$. Here you need the fact that your base set has at least $4$ different elements.

Answer (score 1):

we should create elements in the form of $(ab)(cd) \implies {4 \choose 2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=3 $

Why did we divided by $2$? Since $(ab)(cd)=(cd)(ab)$