# Non-existence of $\mathfrak{S}_n \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{A}_{n+1}$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the symmetric group (permutations of $n$ items) and let $\mathfrak{A}_n$ be the alternate group.

For $n \geq 5$, I have to show that there is no injective morphism $\mathfrak{S}_n \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{A}_{n+1}$.

If such a morphism exists, then its image $H$ is a subgroup of order $n!$ of $\mathfrak{A}_{n+1}$ which is of order $(n+1)!/2$, so $H$ has index $(n+1)/2$  and this is only possible when $n$ is odd. That's all I have... I guess the simplicity of $\mathfrak{A}_{n+1}$ will be a key argument but I don't see where I could use it.

Hints and/or solutions are welcome !

Comment: You should probably say if $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $\mathfrak{A}_n$ are the symmetric and alternating groups on $n$ objects: the fraktur font is not the usual notation.

Comment: Ah, in my country (France), it is undoubtingly the most common notation. I'll specify it.

Comment: If I remember the strategy correctly, you should look for some element of $S_n$ which has too big centralizer for $A_{n+1}$ being able to provide.

Comment: Also, it is a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470469/rotmans-exercise-2-8-s-n-cannot-be-imbedded-in-a-n1?rq=1) and the answer can be found (for some reason) [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65083/an-easy-proof-that-sn-does-not-embed-into-an1).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see this topic.